# Prioritizing error messages in Python Dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, error-handling

I make an API call and if something goes wrong they return a list of errors: e.g.

```
[
{'field': u'currency', 'message': 'must be USD', 
 'request_pointer': '/customer_bank_accounts/currency'}, 
{'field': 'iban', 'message': 'is invalid', 
'request_pointer': u'/customer_bank_accounts/iban'}]
```

I would like to return one error to the user and prioritise the errors. The errors can come in any order.

I know I can go throw the entire list looking for the first error e.g.

```
for error in errors:
    if error['message'] == 'is invalid' and error['field'] == 'iban'
        return "error message 1"

for error in errors:
    if error['message'] == 'is invalid' and error['field'] == 'country code'
        return "error message 2"
```

but this is ugly code and involves going through the list completely multiple times. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of using dictionaries for inputs. They are easy to store, offer O(1) lookup, and ensure your inputs are separated from your logic.

```
errors = [{'field': u'currency', 'message': 'must be USD', 
           'request_pointer': '/customer_bank_accounts/currency'}, 
          {'field': 'iban', 'message': 'is invalid', 
           'request_pointer': u'/customer_bank_accounts/iban'}]

error_dict = {('is invalid', 'iban'): 'error message 1',
              ('is invalid', 'country code'): 'error message 2'}

for idx, error in enumerate(errors):
    key = (error['message'], error['field'])
    if key in error_dict:
        print(idx, error_dict[key])
```

Comment: In this case, I'm prioritizing by error_dict but with dicts there are no way to keep track of where in the dict the error came. If it was a list I could use the index to assign priority.

Comment: @user7692855, I don't fully grasp. You could use an `OrderedDict` if order of dictionary item matters.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should create your own errors like so

```
class USDException(Exception):
    "Exception Here"
    pass
```

You can then use property error handling techniques to pass the appropriate error such as

```
try:
  dostuff()
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like a matrix.

You build with the first index as message and the second as field. You build before.

Build matrix:

```
code_error['is invalid']['iban'] = 'error message 1'
...
```

Using:

```
return code_error[error['message']][error['field']]
```

I think it will look more beautiful. It will become more organized.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a set of of just the parts of the `errors` list you care about:

```
errorset = set([d['field']+' '+d['message'] for d in errors])
if 'iban is invalid' in errorset:
     return "error message 1"
elif 'country code is invalid' in errorset:
     return "error message 2"
```

Sets have constant lookup time to check if something is a member, so you only iterate through the list when making the easier to read list and adding it to your set.